# Combine multiple custom user taxonomy in single url

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, multi-taxonomy-query, register-taxonomy

I have created custom user taxonomy for user and its working good.

Reference guide:- http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress

Bellow is structure of taxonomy

```
(registered taxonomy)  profession

                              Dietitian (under the profession )



(registered taxonomy) city
                         NewYork(under the city)
```

my slug name name `expert`

Now i want the url something like `www.test.com/expert/dietitian/newyork`
with user which have selected  Dietitian ,  NewYork in user profile. And is there any solution to combine `Dietitian,NewYork`

The url with single terms works like:- `www.test.com/expert/dietitian/`

Comment: You want to redirect the user's page to the subtaxonomy sort of page? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @OmarTariq can you check my updated question.